# Is GPT-4's Latin significantly better than GPT-3?

Tags: latin-on-devices

A month ago, a user posted this question: [Is GPT's Latin significantly better than Google Translate?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/is-gpts-latin-significantly-better-than-google-translate)

But as AI is improving rapidly, GPT-4 is now out. I asked the same two questions (without prompt engineering):

> Potestne GPT recto Latine scribere?

> GPT-3 est AI (intelligentia artificiosa) programma quod potest Latine scribere, sed non est perfectum neque in linguarum notitia neque in compositione. Fortasse possit aliqua modo recte Latine scribere, sed potest etiam errores continere in grammatica, syntaxi, et vocabulis. Si quaeris auxilium in re litterata Latina, GPT-3 potest es propositura compositrice tibi, sed valorizandum erit usquequaque auctorisitas software non erit perfecta.

And the second one:

> Quomodo Sanctus Wenceslaus regebat?

> Sanctus Wenceslaus, communiter Wenceslaus I, Dux Bohemiae, Bohemiae regionem in saeculo 10 (circa 921-935 AD) regebat. Pater, Dux Wratislaus I, fuit dux ex magna provincia Marcomanni et Stiria, mater Drahomíra Ze Stodor princeps erat populorum Varodorum. Sanctus Wenceslaus, certamen praecipue accepit potestatem regni, post eius vices eius matrem Drahomiram et fratrem minorem Boleslaus.
> Sanctus Wenceslaus, princeps christianus, indigenas orthodoxiam et normas christianas promovebat, simulque fines et auctoritatem suam regni pro suorum subditorum levatione extendebat. Ecclesiam sancti Vitio in castro Pragae, Bohemiae fundavit, quod postea magnam basilicam ad caput archiepiscopali templum.
> Sanctus Wenceslaus praeter ecumenicas et politices administrationes, potentiam promovebat comitatus et gentibus circumfluentibus, Magyaris, Polonis, et Saxonibus. Eorum gentium incursionibus bellum et pace resisters, eius regnum prospere a populo circumjacentibus poene reconiungenti.
> Eius politices progressionis non solum ambitio Sed etiam pro tolerentia et concordia inter Christianorum atque indigenes, conabantur. Curavit pontes et viarum stratorum aedificia, agrorum cultionem, atque normas a foro et religiosa instituta capessivit, iustitiam inter cives ac mutuas cooperantiones sustentare.
> Sicut iam memoravimus, fratrem minorem, i.e., Boleslaus Iuriosum, conspiratione, sanctum Wenceslaus ut occidisset. Sanctus Wenceslaus, capite percussus, in ecclesia sancti Cosmae et Damiani anno 935 trucidatione interfectus est, anno viginti octo sequente, sanctus romanus Ecclesiae inclitus.
> In summa, Sanctus Wenceslaus regebat per caritatem fidei Christianae, fortitudo et auctoritas pro pace et prosperitatem populus, ut generosior, pietate et ordine iustitia et a rectores optimo.

What are you thoughts?

Comment: It looks terrible, but aside from that, one gets the impression that a text is first composed in English and then turned into Latin by a bad translation software. E.g. could *Curavit pontes et viarum stratorum aedificia* mean something like “he took care of the building of bridges and paved roads”?

Comment: If one were to ask it the same question in English, we could put that through some translators and probably deduce which one was used. *cough* Google Translate *cough*

Comment: @Adam No translator was used, GPT is a language model. But what's funny is that if the training data contains a lot of content translated by Google (as you may know, numerous websites translate all their pages into all possible languages to reach a wider audience), then it will learn to imitate Google Translate more than classical authors